Not able to rebuild my app after using react-native-firebase/auth
I am building a app and trying to implement googlesignin in it but while implementation its showing an error to rebuild the app react-native-firebase/auth is added . and when  i am trying to rebuild its showing some error in it .
Here's the error -
BUILD FAILED in 9s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
G:\free_bird\mobile-app\back-office-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\auth\ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java:1621: error: pattern matching in instanceof is not
supported in -source 11 if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException collEx) { ^ (use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof) 1 error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 9s.
Here's the code -
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "myapikey",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    databaseURL:""
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize Firebase only if it hasn't been initialized yet
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
    
    // Configure Google Sign-in with the web client ID
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: 'myclientid',
    });
  }, []);

  // Function to handle Google login
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      // Check if Google Play Services are available
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });

      // Sign in with Google
      const response = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const idToken = response?.data?.idToken; // Ensure you get the idToken

      if (!idToken) {
        throw new Error('No ID token found');
      }

      // Create a Google credential with the idToken
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      
      // Sign in with Firebase using the Google credential
      const userCredential = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);

      // Get the user's Firebase ID token
      const token = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();

      console.log('Firebase ID Token:', token);
      setToken(token); // Update the context with the token

      // Store the token in AsyncStorage for future use
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('authToken', token);

    } catch (error) {
      // Log and display any errors that occur during sign-in
      console.error("Google Sign-In Error:", error, " code: ", error.code);
      Alert.alert('Login Error', error?.message);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false); // Ensure loading state is reset
    }
  };

heres the build gradel (project Level) file - -

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "20.7.0"
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

Here is the build Gradel App level -
enter image description here

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
react {
    /* Folders */
}
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.applicationName"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.applicationName"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('my-release-key.keystore')
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
     implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3")) // Or latest BOM version
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.6.0") // Or latest version
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

Gradel version - 8.0.1
jdk Version - 17
Here's my package.json file -
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.14.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^21.3.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.6",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.12.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.1.9",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"

I even tried to rewrite the whole code but i am stuck in this issue from last 2 days .

If we reformat the error message, we get this:
BUILD FAILED in 9s
error Failed to install the app.
Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

G:\free_bird\mobile-app\back-office-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\auth\ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java:1621:
error: pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 11 if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException collEx) { ^ (use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof) 1

error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s.

From this message, we can see that the actual problem is this:

pattern matching in instanceof is not supported in -source 11

And the recommended correction is this:

use -source 16 or higher to enable pattern matching in instanceof

Here, -source 11 is referring to the version of Java. Java is the language upon which Android applications and is what react-native interfaces with when your code is packaged into an application.
As you are getting a message about needing to update to Java 16 or later to support that feature the library is using, you need to adjust the Android versions you have configured:
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 23
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 33

In v30 to v33, Android was compiled using Java 11. In v34, Android started supporting Java 17.
To support this, you must use buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0" and compileSdkVersion = 34 (at the time of writing) (see documentation).
Additionally, Google Play requires you target an SDK released within the last year, so you must use targetSdkVersion=34 as of August 31, 2024.
This leaves you with the following: (comments added for clarity, remove before use)
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"   # Java 17 requirement
minSdkVersion = 23             # @react-native-firebase/auth requirement
compileSdkVersion = 34         # Java 17 requirement
targetSdkVersion = 34          # Google Play publishing requirement

